# jquery get the position half of one div

Tags: jquery, offset

I met some basic problem in jquery, but I can't figure it out.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/pdQsY/

How do I get the position of half of a div.(mouseover left 200px of the div, output font color `#ff0`. mouseover right 200px of the div, output font color #336)

I use `e.pageX - div.offsetLeft`, but this echo `NaN`, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.offset().left` instead of the non-existent jQuery property `offsetLeft`.

For efficiency considerations, you should cache the `$("#main")` and `$('p')` variable. You're calling this twice in your `mousemove` handler. The `mousemove` handler is fired very often, so you end up calling `$("#main")` over thousand times, easily.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pdQsY/2/

```
var $main  = $("#main");
var $p = $('p');
$main.mousemove(function(e) {
    var mouseX = e.pageX;
    var offsetLeft = $main.offset().left;
    if(mouseX < 200 + offsetLeft){
         $p.css('color','#ff0');
    } else {
         $p.css('color','#336');
    }
    $p.html(mouseX - offsetLeft);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```